# PHP5 - SQLSRV too slow

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm using the sqlsrv to fetch data from a sql server database. This database is in a diferent server of PHP (outside local network).

I using a query with lots of UNION. If I run the query on Management Studio it takes around 4-5 seconds to fetch all the data... But if I use the PHP and sqlsrv it takes around 57 seconds!

This is the code I'm using:

```
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$u, "PWD"=>$p, "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    $errors = sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ERRORS);
    $tsql = $query;
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
    $json = array();
            do {
                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $json[] = $row;                  
                }
                } while ( sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) );  
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how much data are you sending and retrieving? If the DB isn't local you would expect it take longer. Either don't send/return as much data, use sproc or another method to execute on DB, or move the DB to the machine with php exe on.

Comment: You have to see if the duration is based on the DB processing time (so you have to code a better query, setup indexes, check DB server resources, ...) or network transfer time (to much data, to many results, network contention, ...).

Comment: I have a similar problem. To get PHP to work with Linux, I had to install `php7.2-sybase`. When I use Microsoft SQL tools, I get very rapid response times. When I use PHP, I get massive delays and timeouts. So either the PHP library is broken, or the driver's are broken.

I think where the two other comments miss the point is it's fast using Microsoft Tools. It's not a big packet, network problems, etc.

Did you ever manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$this->stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $sql, null, array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD ));
```

SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC    Lets you access rows in any order but will not reflect changes in the database. static is the abbreviated form of SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC.

Please take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver

Comment: add some explanation please

Comment: I cannot speak english well. Please have  a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver

Comment: It said SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC Lets you access rows in any order but will not reflect changes in the database.

static is the abbreviated form of SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC.

Comment: In my opinion if you access result data only forward then you would be better to choice forward cursor mode.. But you cannot use sqlsrv_num_rows. if you want count the "select query" result then do one more count query.

Comment: Please add these comments to your answer so everyone can benefit from it